# Alternate grunt.js tasks for dev/prod environments

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I am trying to set up my grunt.js file so it only runs the `min` task when running on my production server - when running on my local dev server I don't want to `min` my code with every change as it is unnecessary.

Any ideas on how grunt.js can differentiate between dev/prod environments?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Register a production task:

```
// on the dev server, only concat
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);

// on production, concat and minify
grunt.registerTask('prod', ['concat', 'min']);
```

On your dev server run `grunt` and on your production run `grunt prod`.

You can setup finer grain targets per task as well:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  min: {
    dev: {
      // dev server minify config
    },
    prod: {
      // production server minify config
    }
  }
});
grunt.registerTask('default', ['min:dev']);
grunt.registerTask('prod', ['min:prod']);
```

Comment: +1 Also, couple that with a grunt watch setup for dev and you're laughing :)

Comment: Good idea. Thank you so much.