# Using Grunt to set environment based variables

Tags: gruntjs

I'm looking at grunt-string-replace to accomplish changing variables in my files to an environment specific variable.  However, when I try to run the grunt script below I get this warning: "Task min:dev not found". But in this code I have that defined:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        min: {
            dev: {
                "string-replace": {
                    dist: {
                        files: {
                            "/newrelic.js": "/newrelic.js"
                        },
                        options: {
                            replacements: [
                                {
                                    pattern: /$APPNAME/ig,
                                    replacement: "services"
                                },
                                {
                                    pattern: /$ENV/ig,
                                    replacement: "nonprod"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            prod: {
                pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
                uglify: {
                    options: {
                        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
                    },
                    build: {
                        src: 'src/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
                        dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

// Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-string-replace');

// Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['min:dev']);
    grunt.registerTask('prod', ['min:prod']);

};
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the manual? The [getting started guide](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#project-and-task-configuration) states that the tasks expect their configuration to be *specified in a property of the same name*. You have no 'min' task defined, thus it's erroring.

The top-level keys of the config object need to match the task names, and then you define 'targets' (eg, 'dev' or 'prod') within the task config.

So, here's your Gruntfile re-worked. I have not tested this so I can't promise it will work, but it will certainly lead you in the right direction:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        "string-replace": {                 
            dev: {
                files: {
                    "/newrelic.js": "/newrelic.js"
                },
                options: {
                    replacements: [{
                        pattern: /$APPNAME/ig,
                        replacement: "services"
                    }, {
                        pattern: /$ENV/ig,
                        replacement: "nonprod"
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            prod: {
                options: {
                    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
                },
                build: {
                    src: 'src/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
                    dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-string-replace');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['string-replace:dev']);
    grunt.registerTask('prod', ['uglify:prod']);
};
```

Comment: Yes, I did but I also looked at this for something more specific to my use case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800205/alternate-grunt-js-tasks-for-dev-prod-environments.  How is that working then and upvoted 15 times?

Comment: The author in that thread mentions they are using the min *task*. You are not using a min task.

Answer (score 1):

think your trying to do this, this fragment will put the environment variable SOME_ENV, into the grunt config, the replace is simply giving you a easy way to do ${SOME_ENV} placeholders in files for replacement

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg : grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        SOME_ENV: process.env.SOME_ENV,
        copy: {
            files: [
                {expand: true, cwd: "src/", src: ["*.*", "**/*.*"], dest: "./build",}
            ],
            options: {
            // Replace ${MEH} in files with grunt.config.get("MEH"),
            // eg ${SOME_ENV} 
            // == grunt.config.get("SOME_ENV")
            // == process.env.SOME_ENV == systems SOME_ENV environment var
                process: function (content, srcpath) {
                    return content.replace(
                        /\$\{([a-zA-Z.]+)\}/g,
                        function replacer(match, p1, offset, string){
                            var value = grunt.config.get(p1);
                            grunt.log.write("  in file '" + srcpath + "'\n    replacing '" + match + "'\n    with '" + value + "'\n"); 
                            return value;
                        });
                    }
            },
        }
    });

    // Production Build Tools
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

    // Default Production Build task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy']);
};
```