# Handling concat in prod with non-concat in dev

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I'm currently working on a large angular.js project. I use grunt to concat/uglify all of my files into one large target.js file, which I then include on my index page.

I've come to the realization that this makes it quite difficult to debug in the dev environment since the code is then all on one line and super ugly. I thought about setting up a second grunt task that leaves the files pretty and separate (see this answer: [Alternate grunt.js tasks for dev/prod environments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13800205)) but then I have the problem of having to include all of the files on the index page when in dev, but removing those references and referencing just the ugly concat target in production.

I'm hoping to find a solution that allows me to keep pretty code in dev and ugly concat code in prod using grunt. I considered just adding script tags on the fly when in dev, and then somehow removing them when I use the production task, but this seems like a headache that might not be necessary, as well as I don't know how I would determine what script tags need to be removed/replaced.

I'm not 100% sold on this approach, as I'm just beginning the project and want to get this right the first time, so if you have a suggestion that better handles this situation, I would be open to accepting that answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use the [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) and [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) . That way you can define a block of ressources (css / js) that will be concatenated only when you execute the usemin task.

For example :

index.html :

```
<!-- build:js js/app.js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/thing-controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/models/thing-model.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/thing-view.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Gruntfile.js :

```
// simple build task
grunt.registerTask('build', [
  'useminPrepare',
  'concat:generated',
  'usemin'
]);
```

That way, files will be concatenated only at build time, leave your index.html will all the single references untouched in DEV mode

For more details / example, see : https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin