# Conditional js minification with Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I have single page angular app which codes are minified and concated before build.
It works fine with [*grunt use-min*](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) task and build blocks in index.html

```
<!-- build:js js/components.min.js -->
<script src="components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- other bower components -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js js/app.min.js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!-- other application specific js files -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

It at the end creates two files: app.min.js and components.min.js.

But now **I need to parametrize grunt task to generate app.min.js based on parameter**. (I need one build where everything will be minified for production and other one - without minified application code - for "business" purpose).

How to configure useminPrepare to sometimes take all the blocks and sometimes no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternate grunt.js tasks for dev/prod environments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800205/alternate-grunt-js-tasks-for-dev-prod-environments)

Comment: I know how to parametrize grunt task to call another portion of tasks for dev and prod purpose but my question is more specific how to configure usemin to take only selected (somehow?) blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't get any valid answer here is my work-around:

1. create separate grunt task for 'business' build
2. regex-replace all usemin build comments that are not wanted before processing index.hmtl with useminPrepare
3. make all processing
4. restore index.html from backup