# Angularjs and gruntfile double index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

this is my tree app:

```
src
|
|
--- publicModule1
--- app.js
--- index.html
```

In app.js there is a routing that every path is concatenate in a ctx context root path declared in Gruntfile.
Example:  ctxRoot = /public
          app.js has a state called /module1

so for call module1 the path is /public/module1.

My question is:

my new configuration is:

```
src
|
|
--- publicModule1
**--- privateModule1**  
--- app.js
--- index.html
```

Is it possible to have another index that refer the new Module for import libraries, other js ecc ecc?

I want to change the ctxRoot because when a user call /private/privateModule1, the webapp can refer to indexNew.html and when  user call /public/publicModule1, the webapp can refer to index.html with the old CtxRoot in gruntFile

Comment: Yes and no are you trying to have it load new modules dynamically (lazy load) or are you trying to have a completely separate app that re-uses some of the modules from the "public" portion of the app?  Either option is possible but lazy loading and keeping the app running is more complicated, re-using modules with a different index.html that loads the script is no problem though.

Comment: @shaunhusain the second that you have say. I want unique app that call public index with public import and also call private index with private modules

Comment: Sure no problem with that just a matter of serving up a new index.html from that other folder (most servers default to looking for index.html if no file is specified on a given path) In your grunt config you might have separate configurations for building the private and the public side so they each have a bundled optimized js file but pretty common to have a set of "core" modules and then "public" and "private" specific modules for particular UIs being made.

Comment: @shaunhusain thank, Have you an example of the new gruntfile?

Comment: well I don't see the original gruntfile here so couldn't begin to tell you how to update it (depends on what grunt plugins you're already using which parts would be relevant, but basically anything dealing with JS, uglify usemin etc).  Personally have moved on to using Gulp for most of my projects, an even more modern build tool option is webpack.  With grunt though you basically have targets for the config for each plugin  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800205/alternate-grunt-js-tasks-for-dev-prod-environments